# how to use Bitmap for Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: bitmap, xamarin.forms, icons

How can I use bitmap from Xamarin Forms? This is used to be on my Android project, but I would like to use something like this from Xamarin Forms. I don't want to do any renders or platform specific. If I can just do it in Forms will be great. 
Any idea?

review forms :

```
     private async void GetIcon()
        {
            Weather weather = await Core.GetWeather();

            var bitmap = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + weather.Icon + ".png")) };

DisplayIcon.bitmap ?

        }
```

xaml :

```
 <Image x:Name="DisplayIcon" Source ="{Binding bitmap}" />
```

ends here *******

****old post****

```
private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
        {
            Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
                if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                }
            }

            return imageBitmap;
        }

        private async void displayIcon()
        {
            Weather weather = await Core.GetWeather();
            if (weather != null)
            {

                var bitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl("http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + weather.Icon + ".png");
                Icon2.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
        }
```

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason binding the Image didn't work as I expected. However, I found this workaround as a solution.

I add this to C#

```
var bitmap = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + weather.Icon + ".png")) };

            DisplayIcon.Source = bitmap.Source;
```

and this to XAML

```
<Image x:Name="DisplayIcon"/>
```

Thank you all for your answers .

Answer (score 0):

[SkiaSharp](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/skiasharp/basics/bitmaps/) has an extensive support for bitmaps, with plenty of [examples](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/SkiaSharpForms/SkiaSharpFormsDemos), no renderers or platform code required. (for bitmaps)

Comment: if you look at his example, he is just loading pngs, not bmp

Comment: Right, I didn't notice! In this case, it's just needed an Image view, isn't it?

Comment: Please check my review . I may missing how to display the actual image using xaml. Thanks !

Comment: @Pxaml That's a different question, for that you should follow Jason's comment or have a look at the samples https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WorkingWithImages

Comment: well , thats exactly what I did if you check my update